# Firebase Cloud Messaging Android open running instance of app from tray instead of new instance

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good afternoon!

I am working on integrating FCM into my android app, and everything is generally working well. With the app in the foreground, the notification is handled properly, and when the app is in the background, a notification appears in the system tray, as expected. My issue is that when I click the notification in the system tray, it opens a new instance of the app instead of the app that is running in the background.

This is not ideal for 2 reasons:

1). The running instance of the app actually handles the notification when it arrives (from the background), then when the user clicks the notification in the tray and creates a new instance, in which the notification is considered already considered "Handled" thanks to the old instance... not my intended result.

2). Less important but still not great UX, the new instance forces the user to sit through my splash screen and invisible sign in functions to happen again, even though the app was already running in the background.

How can I have the notification in the system tray open the running / existing instance of the app from the background instead of a new instance? The documentation states that you can call a specific intent from the notification, but this still opens up a new instance of the app, unless I am missing something.

Let me know if any of my code might be of help. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do. Are you saying you just want the notification to bring an existing activity stack to the foreground instead of creating a new activity?  In either case, you are not really creating a new "instance of the app".  Your app almost certainly only has one process, but it can have different activity stacks.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the quick reply. You are correct, I would like to bring an existing activity stack to the foreground instead of creating a new activity when the user clicks the notification. The issue is that it restarts the app when clicked, right back to the splash screen and login activity. I do not want this. I would like to simply bring forward the running activity from the back stack to the foreground. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible.  Cloud Messaging is going to launch an intent which triggers the creation of a new Activity.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the update, that was my understanding from the documentation, but I wanted to just make sure I wasn't missing something. I will try to feed it an intent to at least skip the splash screen and work around some of the other issues I am having. Thanks again for the quick turn around!